# weird sandbox violation

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, actionscript-2

I receive the following message when i start writing something inside a textField:

```
*** Security Sandbox Violation ***
SecurityDomain 'http :// localhost/crossdomain.xml' tried to access incompatible context 'file:///C|/.../Login.swf'
```

I don't see a reason for that message, but it seems that this message is thrown when i do Key.isDown (i have an AS2 SWF which i load in my AS3 SWF - i use it to detect mouse middle clicks).

crossdomain.xml was loaded previously with Security.loadPolicy and with no problems.

Any ideas?

the error is thrown inside Key.idDown method (which is called at each ENTER_FRAME event). this is the code used to detect mouse middle and right clicks:

```
import flash.system.Security; 
Security.allowInsecureDomain("*"); 
Security.allowDomain("*"); 
var mouseButtons:Function = ASnative(800, 2); 
onEnterFrame = function() { 
  _root._width = 0; 
  _root._height = 0; 
  if (mouseButtons(2)) { 
    _root._width = 2; 
  } 
  if (mouseButtons(4)) { 
    _root._height = 2; 
  } 
};
```

Comment: Can you share some code to demonstrate the problem?  It seems very odd to me that a text field would throw a security sandbox error.

Comment: the error is thrown inside Key.idDown method (which is called at each ENTER_FRAME event).

this is the code used to detect mouse middle and right clicks:


import flash.system.Security;
Security.allowInsecureDomain("*");
Security.allowDomain("*");

var mouseButtons:Function = ASnative(800, 2);

onEnterFrame = function() { 
 _root._width = 0;
 _root._height = 0;
 
 if (mouseButtons(2))
 {
  _root._width = 2;
 }
 
 if (mouseButtons(4))
 {
  _root._height = 2;
 }
};

Comment: Could you please post your cross-domain policy file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's nothing but it's strange the space between "http://" and "localhost/crossdomain.xml". Check the address that you are calling or is just a cut&paste error ?

There's no reason for a TextField to throw SecurityExecpion, maybe something is fighting with the Flash verifier